# XSL: position() in template match vs position() in select

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I don't understand the following behaviour:

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <article>Title1</article>
    <other>Other</other>
    <article>Title2</article> 
    <article>Title3</article>
</list>
```

**XSL 1:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="article" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list/*">
        Content: <xsl:value-of select="."/> | Position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> | Last: <xsl:value-of select="last()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output of XSL1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Content: Title1 | Position: 1 | Last: 3
Content: Title2 | Position: 2 | Last: 3
Content: Title3 | Position: 3 | Last: 3
```

So far so good.

Now if I change the match above from `list/*` to `list/*[2]` I don't get any output. I think that is because the second item is `<other>` which doesn't match `select="article"`.

What weird is that when I change the match to `list/*[3]` I get the line where the position is 2:

```
<xsl:template match="list/*[3]">
    Content: <xsl:value-of select="."/> | Position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/> | Last: <xsl:value-of select="last()"/>
</xsl:template>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
Content: Title2 | Position: 2 | Last: 3
```

Why does `position()` work different in the template than in the match-clause?

Comment: `list[2]` and `list[position() != 2]` are all trying to select `list`, but aren't you trying to select children of list? So instead of changing `list/*` to `list[2]`, wouldn't you need to change it to `list/*[2]` (which should match the `article` with the content `Title2`).

Comment: Also, the position of `other` doesn't matter because of the apply-templates selecting only `article`.

Comment: Oh, that is an unfortunate typo :(, I'm selecting `list/*[2]` of course. I updated the question.

Comment: Ditto @DanielHaley's comment.  I don't know the details of the actual implementation, but conceptually, `<xsl:apply-templates select="article" />` selects all the `article` children of the context node (in this case, the parent `list` element) and passes those along for processing.  Since the `<xsl:template match="list/*">` template call is only ever given those three `<article>` elements, the `<other>` element is completely irrelevant: `position` in this case is only evaluating the position of each `<article>` element within the group of `<article>` elements passed in by the earlier `select`.

Comment: It should be irrelevant. But it isn't. `list/*[1]`, `list/*[3]` and `list/*[4]` yield the 3 articles. `list/*[2]` yields no output. Try it out.

Comment: Put differently: setting `list/*[3]` as template match creates the output with position 3 instead of 2: `Content: Title2 | Position: 2 | Last: 3`

Comment: It depends on where you put the expression.  Since the upstream expression is limited to `apply-templates` **`select="article"`**, anything downstream to that is limited to only those `article` elements.  `output` is not an `article` element, so it isn't counted at all.  Selecting `list/*[3]` etc. explicitly selects child number 3 out of all `list` children -- which is qualitatively different from counting the position of the current `article` out of all `article` elements to which a template is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath expression

```
list/*[3]
```

means the the third child element of a `<list>` element.  The node test `[3]` is evaluated relative to the nodes selected by the preceding path expression.

On the other hand, XSLT section 4 specifies that

> an outermost expression (i.e. an expression that is not part of
>   another expression) gets its context as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - the context
>     position comes from the position of the current node in the current
>     node list; the first position is 1

In the body of your template, `position()` and `last()` appear as outermost expressions.  They are therefore evaluated with respect to the current node list, and that template applies only when the current node list consists of the three nodes selected by

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="article" />
```

when `<list>` was the current node.  That node list contains exactly three nodes, regardless of how many or which of them are matched by the template.  Moreover, the position of a given node in that node list is not necessarily the same as the position of that node in the node list matched by the subexpression `list/*` of the template's match expression, nor the same as its position in the node list matched by the template's full match expression.  There is only an incidental relationship between the position measures.

Comment: So `match="*[3]"` always checks if elements are the third child of their parent, no matter what was `select`ed?

Comment: Is there any way at all to "pass information" from `select=` to `match=`?

Comment: @FabianZeindl, not as I understand you, no.  Sections 5.1 and 5.2 of the XSLT 1.0 spec seems to be clear on this: the determination of which templates match a given node is performed statically.  In particular, "A node matches a pattern if the node is a member of the result of evaluating the pattern as an expression with respect to some possible context; the possible contexts are those whose context node is the node being matched or one of its ancestors."

Comment: @FabianZeindl, but you can use narrower patters in your `apply-templates` in the first place, or apply templates that accept a parameter, or that operate in a different mode.  In these ways you can fine tune which template is applied and/or pass additional data *into* the template.

Comment: `A node matches a pattern if the node is a member of the result of evaluating the pattern as an expression with respect to some possible context; the possible contexts are those whose context node is the node being matched or one of its ancestors.`

I read half of the spec, but I have to admit that I don't understand that sentence.

Comment: @FabianZeindl, XSLT patterns are, roughly, members of that subset of XPath expressions that evaluate to node sets and do not depend on any attribute of the evaluation context other than the context node.  The sentence is saying that to determine whether a node matches a pattern, one tests, in principle, whether that node is a member of one of the node sets resulting from evaluating the expression with that node or one of its ancestor nodes as the context node.  I hope that helps.

Comment: It does. `XPath expressions that [...] do not depend on any attribute of the evaluation context other than the context node`. That is what I meant with not being able to pass information from `select` into `match`.

Comment: Leaving the root-node aside for a moment, is the sentence equivalent to saying the following: I can construct an absolute xpath for the context-node like this: /node()[1][self::A]/node()[4][self::B]/.... Within that context a node then matches a pattern if it matches the xpath $absolutePath//$matchPattern?

Comment: @FabianZeindl, I'm having trouble interpreting what you mean, but it doesn't seem quite right.  To put it in XPath terms, I would say instead that a node *N* matches a given relative pattern if it is among the nodes obtained by evaluating the XPath expression `ancestor-or-self::node()/$matchPattern` with *N* as the context node.